# Find: how to discover which directory contains a SlackBuild file?

Tags: find

With this line

```
find mydir/ \( -exec test -d '{}'/.svn \; -or -exec test -d {}/.git \; -or -exec test -d {}/CVS \; \) -print -prune
```

is really easy to discover which directory contains a subdirectory `.git` or `CSV` os `.svn`.

I want to discover which dir contains a SlackBuild file. I have tried this but without success:

```
find mydir/ -type d \( -exec test -f {}/*SlackBuild \; \) -print
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all files matching and execute `dirname` for them:

```
find mydir/ -type f -name '*.SlackBuild' -exec dirname {} +
```

Also, for GNU utils, `dirname` has the `-z` option for zero separation of the output arguments (similar to `-print0` of `find`).